# How to overload numeric operators in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I was recently working with Python and wanted to use another way of finding square roots. For example I wanted to find square root of n with Newton-Raphson approximation. I need to overload the overload the `**` (only when you raise a number to 0.5),o perator as well as `math.sqrt()`, because I have several older projects that could be sped up by doing so and replacing all `math.sqrt()` and `**(0.5)` with another function isn't ideal.

Could this be done in Python?

Is it possible to overload either `**` or `math.sqrt`?

Any helpful links are also much appreciated.

```
def Square_root(n):
    r = n/2
    while(abs(r-(n/r)) > t):
        r = 0.5 * (r + (n/r))
    return r

print(2**(0.5)) ## changes to print(Square_root(2))
print(math.sqrt(2)) ## that also becomes print(Square_root(2))
```

Comment: You can overload `**` (or any other operator) only for the members of your custom classes. I do not believe you can redefine `math.sqrt()`.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but you really shouldn't do it. Anyone else looking through the source code of the program will expect `**` and `math.sqrt()` to work like they do normally, so the different behavior will probably cause a lot of confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can't change the behavior of [`__pow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for built-in types.

Long answer: you can subclass the `float`, but it will require additional coding and refactoring of the input values of the program, to the new `float` class with overwritten operators and functions.

And you can overwrite the `math.sqrt`, but this is not **recommended**:

```
import math
math.sqrt = lambda x, y: print(x, y)
math.sqrt(3, 2)
# 3 2
```

This will require the custom function to have the same signature.

Comment: Thank you. The code snippet was what I was looking for. As for __pow__ I guess I will have to leave that as is.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to overload languages *int* and *float* objects - you can use variants of [magic functions](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php). In order to be consistent, you'll have to write a lot of code.

A lot of work. Python is for lazy people - if you like to write a lot, stick to Java or C++ :)